# Microsoft SQL Linux [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, server

Im trying to setup a mssql on a linux machine (CentOS). But the application cannot connect through it because of:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error.

This is the error being thrown by the application. I've already disabled my firewall and configured applications OS' host file to point to the linux server. Thank you

This is configuration in my mssql.conf

[image: mssql configuration]

This is the application's caught error

[image]

In windows the settings that Im using is I enable named pipes, tcp/ip in the configuration of the sql. Is there a translation to this in linux?

Comment: What does `sudo cat /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf | grep tlsprotocols` tell you?

Comment: hi, it tells me nothing. but when I cat /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf it says [sqlagent] enabled = false [EULA] accepteula = Y

Comment: I've already set my sql agent to true. The issue still presists

Comment: It tells you plenty. If you're not going to configure TLS connections on SQL Server (see: [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-encrypted-connections)) then you should probably not tell your application to use encryption in its connection string(s).

Comment: Hi, But the application is not explicitly using encryption in its connection strings

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. What sytem are you using to run the application from? Older systems (up to Windows 7) have old ODBC and OLE DB drivers. I recommend updating them:

[OLE DB Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
[ODBC Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

If that does not help try running the same scenario on newer system and see it the problem persists.

Also chceck if the software which is causing these problems have configurable connection string. If so change OLEDBProvider to OLEDBDriver.